# using system.windows.forms reference not showing up asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, reference, shared-libraries

I am trying to add a reference to the library stated in the question. But it is throwing an error on the 'windows' section of the library reference. Can anyone help me.

Thanks!

Comment: **Don't use System.Windows.Forms in web applications** - Why are you doing that ?

Comment: Never mind i have solved it...turns out i was being stupid. I did not have the reference added.

Answer (score 4):

Step 1: Go to "Solution Explorer"

Step 2: Right click on "Add reference"

Step 3: Search in the ".net" tab for the reference for "System.Windows.dll" Or "System.Windows.Forms.dll" (don't know which one is present there but I would prefer the later) and add it.

This should resolve your problem.