# GDI Rendering outside of a Windows Forms app

Tags: c#, image-processing, gdi+, gdi, cleartype

I have a class that renders text to an image.  It was working fine until I tried to use the Calibri font.  Calibri is rendered without any font smoothing.  After [some](http://www.resolversystems.com/news/?p=192) [research](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dc4cd997-7662-4ddf-88cf-06006279c374/graphicsdrawstring-does-not-draw-colored-antialiasing) I determined that the cause is that `Graphics.DrawString()` uses `GDI+`, and I need to use `GDI`.  The [solution presented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171753(v=vs.110).aspx) is to use `TextRenderer.DrawText()` instead.  But, `TextRenderer` is in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace, and mine is not a Windows Forms app.

Should I just reference the System.Windows.Forms.dll in my project?  This class should be considered middle-tier.  It doesn't care if the application is web-based, windows forms, WPF, or whatever.  The output is an [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image(v=vs.110).aspx).  In my specific case, I am using it on the web.  And I don't like the idea of referencing `System.Windows.Forms` from an ASP.Net application.  [Several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000470/using-system-windows-forms-reference-not-showing-up-asp-net-4-0#comment21070526_15000470) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721967/system-windows-forms-in-asp-net-3-5#comment534238_722400) and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10850652/361684) on StackOverflow suggest that ASP.Net applications should not reference windows forms dlls.

So, is there a non-windows-forms way of rendering text via GDI?  Or is this case an exception to the rule of not referencing windows forms dlls from ASP.Net?

Comment: Referencing System.Windows.Forms.dll is not a problem.  It isn't spontaneously going to try to create desktop windows on your web server.  Nothing happens until you create an instance of a class, as normal in .NET.  These kind of comments fall in the "don't really know what it does, looks ugly, must be bad" category.  TextRenderer is a thin wrapper around DrawTextEx().

Comment: That's what I figured.  Seems like `TextRenderer` belongs in `System.Graphics`.